# Dividing an even number into N parts each part being a multiple of 2

Tags: python, algorithm, math, numbers

Let's assume I have the number `100` which I need to divide into N parts each of which shouldn't exceed 30 initially. So the initial grouping would be (30,30,30). The remainder (which is 10) is to be distributed among these three groups by adding 2 to each group in succession, thus ensuring that each group is a multiple of 2. The desired output should therefore look like (34,34,32).

Note: The original number is always even.

I tried solving this in Python and this is what I came up with. Clearly it's not working in the way I thought it would. It distributes the remainder by adding 1 (and not 2, as desired) iteratively to each group.

```
num = 100
parts = num//30  #Number of parts into which 'num' is to be divided

def split(a, b):
  result = ([a//b + 1] * (a%b) + [a//b] * (b - a%b))
  return(result)

print(split(num, parts))
```

Output:

```
[34, 33, 33]
```

Desired output:

```
[34, 34, 32]
```

Comment: *"which shouldn't exceed 30 initially"* Why? Why shouldn't they exceed 30? And what's so special about "initially"? Don't you just care about the final result?

Comment: i'm trying to implement this algorithm for plotting some data. I need to make sure that the number of entries along the axes don't go beyond 60. In the worst case, if the number is 59, this algorithm will make sure that there are only 59 entries along the axes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Simplified problem: forget about multiples of 2

First, let's simplify your problem for a second. Forget about the multiples of 2. Imagine you want to split a non-necessarily-even number `n` into `k` non-necessarily-even parts.

Obviously the most balanced solution is to have some parts be `n // k`, and some parts be `n // k + 1`.

How many of which? Let's call `r` the number of parts with `n // k + 1`. Then there are `k - r` parts with `n // k`, and all the parts sum up to:

```
   (n // k) * (k - r) + (n // k + 1) * r
== (n // k) * (k - r) + (n // k) * r + r
== (n // k) * (k - r + r) + r
== (n // k) * k + r
```

But the parts should sum up to `n`, so we need to find `r` such that:

```
n == (n // k) * k + r
```

Happily, you might recognise Euclidean division here, with `n // k` being the quotient and `r` being the remainder.

This gives us our `split` function:

```py
def split(n, k):
    d,r = divmod(n, k)
    return [d+1]*r + [d]*(k-r)
```

Testing:

```py
print( split(50, 3) )
# [17, 17, 16]
```

### Splitting into multiples of 2

Now back to your `split_even` problem. Now that we have the generic function `split`, a simple way to solve `split_even` is to use `split`:

```py
def split_even(n, k):
    return [2 * x for x in split(n // 2, k)]
```

Testing:

```py
print( split_even(100, 3) )
# [34, 34, 32]
```

### Generalisation: multiples of `m`

It's trivial to do the same thing with multiples of a number `m` other than 2:

```py
def split_multiples(n, k, m=2):
    return [m * x for x in split(n // m, k)]
```

Testing:

```py
print( split_multiples(102, 4, 3) )
# [27, 27, 24, 24]
```

Comment: Elegant explanation! appreciate your help

Comment: My thoughts exactly :)

Comment: `split()` worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

This solution is not very clear and easy to follow but it does not need any loops.

Full code:

```py
def split(a,b):
     lower = (a//b//2) * 2
     num = a % (b*2) // 2
     return [lower + 2] * num + [lower] * (b - num)
```

Explanation:

- First get the value of all parts: We round the result of the division (`value // parts`) down to the next even value (`(x // 2) * 2`)
- To get the number of higher values: We use the remainder of the division of `a` in double as many parts and divide it by two to compensate the multiplication
- last: higher numbers are just `lower + 2` times the computed number of higher values and lower numbers are filling the other spaces

Answer (score 1):

My approach here is to create three arrays and sum them, the first two are simple, but the last is a little more complex to follow - it's just repping 2 (by) as many times as is can given the remainder, then repping 0s.

```
# Part 1
np.repeat(first, x//first) 
# Part 2
np.repeat(by, x//first)
# Part 3
np.repeat([by, 0], [(x//first) - ((x - (x//first*first)) // by % by), (x - (x//first*first)) // by % by])
```

Wrapped into a function:

```
def split(x, first, by):
  return(np.repeat(first, x//first) + np.repeat(by, x//first) + np.repeat([by, 0], [(x//first) - ((x - (x//first*first)) // by % by), (x - (x//first*first)) // by % by]))

split(100, 30, 2)
```

Comment: To make it usable and understandable, could you please encapsulate this method into a function, with arguments for the number to split, and the number of parts? Rather than hardcoding 100 and 30.