# How to divide an integer into an array of roughly equal and evenly distributed parts that sum to the original integer?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, division, integer-division

Given an integer `n`, what is an algorithm that can divide it into an array of `d` parts, which has the properties that its members sum to the original integer `n`, are roughly equal in size, and are reasonably evenly distributed throughout the array? e.g. dividing 13 into 10 parts looks something like:

`[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]`

More specifically, it shouldn't look like:

`[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]` (uneven distribution)

`[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4]` (not roughly equal in size)

The parity of the array's members is not important.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dividing an even number into N parts each part being a multiple of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70392403/dividing-an-even-number-into-n-parts-each-part-being-a-multiple-of-2)

Comment: Alternatively, a variant of the [Bresenham line-drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) can be used to interleave your values the way you want. You need to decide when to take a `n/d` and when to take an `n/d + 1`. This is similar to Bresenham's algorithm, which must decides when to move only in the x-direction, and when to move both in the x- and the y-directions.

Comment: @Stef no, that's a different question; I don't care about the parts being multiples of 2, or multiples of anything for that matter.

Comment: See for instance [the code of more_itertools.interleave_evenly](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#interleave_evenly) in python.

Comment: I have answered my own question below, for what it's worth. I asked (and answered) the question because I didn't see an adequate answer to my query elsewhere...

Comment: Was this "no" to a particular thing I said, or to everything I said?

Comment: @Stef no to the multiples of 2 answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a dynamic ratio (`a/b`) in relation to the ratio of the large values to small values (`c/r`) in order to decide the distribution of the remainder after division:

```js
function split(n, d)
{
  if(d === 0)
    return [];

  // Integer division spelled in JavaScript
  const q = Math.floor(n / d);
  const r = n % d;
  const c = d - r;
  
  let out = Array(d);
  let a = 1;
  let b = 1;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < d; i++)
  {
    // Make the ratio a/b tend towards c/r
    if((a * r) < (b * c))
    {
      a++;
      out[i] = q;
    }
    else
    {
      b++;
      out[i] = q + 1;
    }
  }
  
  // Check the array sums to n
  console.log(out, n === out.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));

  return out;
}

split(11, 10);
split(173, 9);
split(13, 10);
split(1773, 19);
```

This produces the output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1], true
[19, 19, 19, 20, 19, 19, 19, 20, 19], true
[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1], true
[93, 93, 94, 93, 93, 94, 93, 93, 94, 93, 93, 94, 93, 93, 94, 93, 93, 94, 93], true
```